# Get all JSON headers from different files

Tags: json, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, papaparse

I'm making a program in React using Hooks that need to read a CSV file and convert it into a JSON, then I want to create a table from the file but the file may change as also the variables and the headers (column name) of each attribute.

How can I get the headers depending on the file so then I can create the table automatically depending on the file and not on the code?

For the CSV to JSON I use `react-papaparse`, and I'm trying to create a basic table to preview the data using React.

**CSVReader**

```
<CSVReader
        onDrop={handleOnDrop}
        onError={handleOnError}
        addRemoveButton
        onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
        config={{ header: true }}
      >
        <span>Drop CSV file here or click to upload.</span>
</CSVReader>
```

Then I assign the data to the state using Hooks

```
  const handleOnDrop = (data) => {
    console.log("---------------");
    console.log(data);
    setFileData(data);
    console.log("---------------");
  };
```

The problem is that the only way to see each data is in code:

```
<div>
        {fileData.map((data, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{data.data.ASEG_LeftLateralVentricle}</li>
        ))}
</div>
```

In some files, the `ASEG_LeftLateralVentricle` has not that name but I also want to show the information of columns 1, 2, ...

**Everything should be done on the front end.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I get all the headers of the JSON file was using the following:

```
const getKeys = (data) => {
    let arr = [];
    if (data) {
      Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        arr = Object.keys(data[key].data);
      });
    }
    return arr;
  };
```